# Localisation Service doesn't start android

Tags: java, android, service, dictionary, osmdroid

I'm working on an android map and i'm trying to use Service class to find the current location of users. I had already succeed to do that whitout Service (directly in the main activity) but given the fact that i'll do network operations to find adresses and points of interest i thinked it was a good training to try Service with current location.

But the problem is my service doesn't start at all even if i reported it in the manifest

my class which extends Service :

`

```
 package toutel.testcarte;

 import org.osmdroid.bonuspack.overlays.Marker;
 import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
 import org.osmdroid.views.MapController;
 import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
 import android.app.Service;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.location.Location;
 import android.location.LocationListener;
 import android.location.LocationManager;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.IBinder;

  public class FindMe extends Service {

private MapView mapView;
private MapController mapController;
private LocationManager lm;

private LocationListener mylocationlistener = new LocationListener() {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        // Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
        GeoPoint myposition = new GeoPoint(location.getLatitude(),
                location.getLongitude());
        mapController.animateTo(myposition);
        mapController.setCenter(myposition);
        mapController.setZoom(17);
        Marker marker = new Marker(mapView);
        marker.setPosition(myposition);
        marker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(marker);
        mapView.invalidate();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
        }

        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mapView.getOverlays().clear();

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

};

public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

    return null;
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 0,
            mylocationlistener);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10000, 0,
            mylocationlistener);
    super.onCreate();
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

public void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();
    lm.removeUpdates(mylocationlistener);
}
```

}
`

Im starting the service in the main activity with

`startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, FindMe.class));`

and i added the service in the manifest :

```
<service android:name = "toutel.testcarte.FindMe"> </service>
```

So what am i doing wrong ?

Thanks !

Comment: First of all use debugger or logging to ensure that 1. `startService(...)` is really called, 2. `FindMe.onCreate()` is not executed. Or did you that already?

Comment: Thanks for your answer i took a look on the logcat but i don't get any error or warnings. I thinked just do startservice(...) was enough do i have to do FindMe.onCreate() in the activity which uses the FindMe class ?

Comment: I meant you should add logging code or breakpoints in debugger to check if the mentioned code is really executed

Comment: Do you mean something like "Log.d(TAG, "My service is working");"  ?

Comment: Any idea? i dont really get why it isn't working...

Comment: Exactly, I meant `Log.d(...)`